# Kubernetes - Can't connect to a service IP from the service's pod

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes

I'm trying to create 3 instances of Kafka and deploy it a local Kubernetes setup. Because each instance needs some specific configuration, I'm creating one RC and one service for each - eagerly waiting for [#18016](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/18016) ;)

However, I'm having problems because Kafka can't establish a network connection to itself when it uses the service IP (a Kafka broker tries to do this when it is exchanging replication messages with other brokers). For example, let's say I have two worker hosts (172.17.8.201 and 172.17.8.202) and my pods are scheduled like this:

- Host 1 (172.17.8.201)

  - `kafka1` pod (10.2.16.1)
- Host 2 (172.17.8.202)

  - `kafka2` pod (10.2.68.1)
  - `kafka3` pod (10.2.68.2)

In addition, let's say I have the following service IPs:

- `kafka1` cluster IP: 11.1.2.96
- `kafka2` cluster IP: 11.1.2.120
- `kafka3` cluster IP: 11.1.2.123

The problem happens when the `kafka1` pod (container) tries to send a message (to itself) using the `kafka1` cluster IP (11.1.2.96). For some reason, the connection cannot established and the message is not sent.

Some more information: If I manually connect to the `kafka1` pod, I can correctly telnet to `kafka2` and `kafka3` pods using their respective cluster IPs (11.1.2.120 / 11.1.2.123). Also, if I'm in the `kafka2` pod, I connect to both `kafka1` and `kafka3` pods using 11.1.2.96 and 11.1.2.123. Finally, I can connect to all pods (from all pods) if I use the pod IPs.

It is important to emphasize that I shouldn't tell the kafka brokers to use the pod IPs instead of the cluster IPs for replication. As it is right now, Kafka uses for replication whatever IP you configure to be "advertised" - which is the IP that your client uses to connect to the brokers. Even if I could, I believe this problem may appear with other software as well.

This problem seems to happen only with the combination I am using, because the exact same files work correctly in GCE. Right now, I'm running:

- Kubernetes 1.1.2
- coreos 928.0.0
- network setup with flannel
- everything on vagrant + VirtualBpx

After some debugging, I'm not sure if the problem is in the workers iptables rules, in kube-proxy, or in flannel.

PS: I posted this question originally as an [Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19930) on their github, but I have been redirected to here by the Kubernetes team. I reword the text a bit because it was sounding like it was a "support request", but actually I believe it is some sort of bug. Anyway, sorry about that Kubernetes team!

---

**Edit:** This problem has been confirmed as a bug https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20391

Comment: i have seen many questions about pod not able to connect to themselves through a service. I am not sure why but there must be a technical reason. Services are meant to load balance requests to pods, so it kinda make sense to me that a Pods should not be talking to the port they themselves serve. 
What you want though, for what you are doing, is to use a Headless service 
http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html#headless-services

Comment: well, it could work for access within the cluster, but I also want the kafka cluster to be accessible from the Internet. When I'm in GCE, I'm using a service with type "LoadBalancer" - and using a reserved IP for the load balancer IP and as the advertised IP. It works fine. Although, the main point of my question is the fact that I can't access a Pod using the service IP - the behaviour in GCE and in my local setup are inconsistent right now, which definitely seems weird.

Comment: you can have both: i use that all the time: you can have a load balanced aervice and a headless service targetting the same pods.

Comment: good to know, thanks! But I'm still looking for answers for the connection thing - as I mentioned in the question, other use cases may find the same problem. I dig a little bit here at stackoverflow and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732597/kubernetes-pod-cant-connect-through-service-to-self-only-to-other-pod-contai seems to be the same problem.

Comment: yes because you can't connect to self through a regular service: use a Headless service.

Comment: Aside from maybe using headless, you should STILL be able to talk to yourself.  What's happening is that traffic exist the container, hits the iptables rules and gets DNAT'ed back to the same container IP.  This is considered a "hairpin turn" which is not allowed by default.  But we enable it, so it should work.

Comment: Are you using the userspace proxy (default) or did you enable the iptables proxy?

Comment: I just tested it from head of tree in both proxy modes and it works.  Depending on which one you use, we can debug different ways.  Also - what cloud environment and is there anything special about your setup regarding networking?

Comment: I'm using the userspace proxy (I mean, it is the container run by the kubelet daemon right?). I think there's nothing special about my setup. It is running locally, all VMs on VirtualBox. I initially created the setup based on the coreos instructions (https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html). The setup has been working perfectly for some weeks, except for this weird case.

Answer (score 5):

for what you want to do you should be using a **Headless Service**
http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html#headless-services

this means setting

`clusterIP: None`

in your **Service**

and that means there won't be an IP associated with the service but it will return all IPs of the Pods selected by the `selector`

Answer (score 1):

### Update: The bug is fixed in v1.2.4

You can try [container hook](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/container-environment/).

```
containers:
  - name: kafka
    image: Kafka
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
            - "some.sh" #some shell scripts to get this pod's IP and notify the other Kafka members that "add me into your cluster"
      preStop:
        exec:
          command:
            - "some.sh" #some shell scripts to get other Kafka pods' IP and notify the other Kafka members that "delete me from your cluster"
```

I have got a similar problems on running 3 mongodb pods as a cluster but the pods cannot access themselves through their serivces' IP.

In addition, has the bug been fixed?