# Kubernetes pod can't access its own service

Tags: networking, docker, kubernetes

## Overview

Pod fails to access its own service (timeout) in a single-node cluster.

- OS is Debian 8
- Cloud is DigitalOcean or AWS (reproduced on both)
- Kubernetes version is 1.5.4
- Kube proxy uses iptables
- Kubernetes installed manually
- I do not use overlay network like weave or flannel

I've changed the service to headless as a workaround but I want to find the real reason behind it.

**Works OK on GCP compute engine node (!?)**. Probably would work fine with --proxy-mode=userspace as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732597/kubernetes-pod-cant-connect-through-service-to-self-only-to-other-pod-contai).

## More details

#### The service

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Service",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2017-04-13T05:29:18Z",
        "labels": {
            "name": "anon-svc"
        },
        "name": "anon-svc",
        "namespace": "anon",
        "resourceVersion": "280",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/anon/services/anon-svc",
        "uid": "23d178dd-200a-11e7-ba08-42010a8e000a"
    },
    "spec": {
        "clusterIP": "172.23.6.158",
        "ports": [
            {
                "name": "agent",
                "port": 8125,
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "targetPort": "agent"
            }
        ],
        "selector": {
            "name": "anon-svc"
        },
        "sessionAffinity": "None",
        "type": "ClusterIP"
    },
    "status": {
        "loadBalancer": {}
    }
}
```

#### Kube-proxy service (systemd)

```
[Unit]
After=kube-apiserver.service
Requires=kube-apiserver.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/kubernetes/bin/hyperkube proxy \
    --master=127.0.0.1:8080 \
    --proxy-mode=iptables \
    --logtostderr=true
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Output from nodes (GCP is where it works), DO (DigitalOcean is where it doesn't work).

#### `$ iptables-save`

GCP:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Apr 13 05:30:33 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4:364]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:60]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7:420]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [19:1460]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-DROP - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-MASQ - [0:0]
:KUBE-NODEPORTS - [0:0]
:KUBE-POSTROUTING - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-2UBKOACGE36HHR6Q - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-5LOF5ZUWMDRFZ2LI - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-5T3UFOYBS7JA45MK - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-YBFG2OLQ4DHWIGIM - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-ZSS7W6PQOP26CZ6F - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-R6UZIZCIT2GFGDFT - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-TF3HNH35HFDYKE6V - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes postrouting rules" -j KUBE-POSTROUTING
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:2379
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:2379
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:2379
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:2379
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:443
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:80
-A KUBE-MARK-DROP -j MARK --set-xmark 0x8000/0x8000
-A KUBE-MARK-MASQ -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000/0x4000
-A KUBE-POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j MASQUERADE
-A KUBE-SEP-2UBKOACGE36HHR6Q -s 10.142.0.10/32 -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-2UBKOACGE36HHR6Q -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -m recent --set --name KUBE-SEP-2UBKOACGE36HHR6Q --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.142.0.10:6443
-A KUBE-SEP-5LOF5ZUWMDRFZ2LI -s 172.17.0.4/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-5LOF5ZUWMDRFZ2LI -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:53
-A KUBE-SEP-5T3UFOYBS7JA45MK -s 172.17.0.4/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-5T3UFOYBS7JA45MK -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:53
-A KUBE-SEP-YBFG2OLQ4DHWIGIM -s 172.17.0.3/32 -m comment --comment "anon/anon-svc:agent" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-YBFG2OLQ4DHWIGIM -p tcp -m comment --comment "anon/anon-svc:agent" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:8125
-A KUBE-SEP-ZSS7W6PQOP26CZ6F -s 172.17.0.1/32 -m comment --comment "anon/etcd:etcd" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-ZSS7W6PQOP26CZ6F -p tcp -m comment --comment "anon/etcd:etcd" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.1:4001
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.20.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.23.6.157/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "anon/etcd:etcd cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 4001 -j KUBE-SVC-R6UZIZCIT2GFGDFT
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.23.6.158/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "anon/anon-svc:agent cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8125 -j KUBE-SVC-TF3HNH35HFDYKE6V
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.20.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.20.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU
-A KUBE-SERVICES -m comment --comment "kubernetes service nodeports; NOTE: this must be the last rule in this chain" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -j KUBE-SEP-5T3UFOYBS7JA45MK
-A KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -m recent --rcheck --seconds 10800 --reap --name KUBE-SEP-2UBKOACGE36HHR6Q --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j KUBE-SEP-2UBKOACGE36HHR6Q
-A KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -j KUBE-SEP-2UBKOACGE36HHR6Q
-A KUBE-SVC-R6UZIZCIT2GFGDFT -m comment --comment "anon/etcd:etcd" -j KUBE-SEP-ZSS7W6PQOP26CZ6F
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-SEP-5LOF5ZUWMDRFZ2LI
-A KUBE-SVC-TF3HNH35HFDYKE6V -m comment --comment "anon/anon-svc:agent" -j KUBE-SEP-YBFG2OLQ4DHWIGIM
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr 13 05:30:33 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Apr 13 05:30:33 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1250:625646]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1325:478496]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
:KUBE-FIREWALL - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr 13 05:30:33 2017
```

DO:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Apr 13 05:38:05 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:52]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:52]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13:798]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [13:798]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-DROP - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-MASQ - [0:0]
:KUBE-NODEPORTS - [0:0]
:KUBE-POSTROUTING - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-3VWUJCZC3MSW5W32 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-CPJSBS35VMSBOKH6 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-K7JQ5XSWBQ7MTKDL - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-WOG5WH7F5TFFOT4E - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-ZSS7W6PQOP26CZ6F - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-R6UZIZCIT2GFGDFT - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-TF3HNH35HFDYKE6V - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes postrouting rules" -j KUBE-POSTROUTING
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.4/32 -d 172.17.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.4/32 -d 172.17.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:2379
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:2379
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:2379
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:2379
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:443
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:80
-A KUBE-MARK-DROP -j MARK --set-xmark 0x8000/0x8000
-A KUBE-MARK-MASQ -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000/0x4000
-A KUBE-POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j MASQUERADE
-A KUBE-SEP-3VWUJCZC3MSW5W32 -s 67.205.156.80/32 -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-3VWUJCZC3MSW5W32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -m recent --set --name KUBE-SEP-3VWUJCZC3MSW5W32 --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 67.205.156.80:6443
-A KUBE-SEP-CPJSBS35VMSBOKH6 -s 172.17.0.3/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-CPJSBS35VMSBOKH6 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:53
-A KUBE-SEP-K7JQ5XSWBQ7MTKDL -s 172.17.0.3/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-K7JQ5XSWBQ7MTKDL -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:53
-A KUBE-SEP-WOG5WH7F5TFFOT4E -s 172.17.0.4/32 -m comment --comment "anon/anon-svc:agent" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-WOG5WH7F5TFFOT4E -p tcp -m comment --comment "anon/anon-svc:agent" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:8125
-A KUBE-SEP-ZSS7W6PQOP26CZ6F -s 172.17.0.1/32 -m comment --comment "anon/etcd:etcd" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-ZSS7W6PQOP26CZ6F -p tcp -m comment --comment "anon/etcd:etcd" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.1:4001
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.20.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.20.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.23.6.158/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "anon/anon-svc:agent cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8125 -j KUBE-SVC-TF3HNH35HFDYKE6V
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.23.6.157/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "anon/etcd:etcd cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 4001 -j KUBE-SVC-R6UZIZCIT2GFGDFT
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 172.20.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y
-A KUBE-SERVICES -m comment --comment "kubernetes service nodeports; NOTE: this must be the last rule in this chain" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -j KUBE-SEP-CPJSBS35VMSBOKH6
-A KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -m recent --rcheck --seconds 10800 --reap --name KUBE-SEP-3VWUJCZC3MSW5W32 --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j KUBE-SEP-3VWUJCZC3MSW5W32
-A KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -j KUBE-SEP-3VWUJCZC3MSW5W32
-A KUBE-SVC-R6UZIZCIT2GFGDFT -m comment --comment "anon/etcd:etcd" -j KUBE-SEP-ZSS7W6PQOP26CZ6F
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-SEP-K7JQ5XSWBQ7MTKDL
-A KUBE-SVC-TF3HNH35HFDYKE6V -m comment --comment "anon/anon-svc:agent" -j KUBE-SEP-WOG5WH7F5TFFOT4E
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr 13 05:38:05 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Apr 13 05:38:05 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1127:469861]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1181:392136]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
:KUBE-FIREWALL - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr 13 05:38:05 2017
```

#### `$ ip route show table local`

GCP:

```
local 10.142.0.10 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.142.0.10
broadcast 10.142.0.10 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.142.0.10
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 172.17.0.0 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope host  src 172.17.0.1
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1
```

DO:

```
broadcast 10.10.0.0 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.0.5
local 10.10.0.5 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.10.0.5
broadcast 10.10.255.255 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.0.5
broadcast 67.205.144.0 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 67.205.156.80
local 67.205.156.80 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope host  src 67.205.156.80
broadcast 67.205.159.255 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 67.205.156.80
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 172.17.0.0 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope host  src 172.17.0.1
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1
```

#### `$ ip addr show`

GCP:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:0a:8e:00:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.142.0.10/32 brd 10.142.0.10 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:d0:6d:28:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: veth1219894: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether a6:4e:d4:48:4c:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: vetha516dc6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether ce:f2:e7:5d:34:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: veth4a6b171: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether ee:42:d4:d8:ca:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

DO:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether da:74:7c:ad:9d:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 67.205.156.80/20 brd 67.205.159.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.0.5/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d874:7cff:fead:9d4d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:66:0a:15:cb:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:85:21:28:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:85ff:fe21:2800/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth95a5fdf: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether 12:2c:b9:80:6c:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::102c:b9ff:fe80:6c60/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: veth3fd8422: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether 56:98:c1:96:0c:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::5498:c1ff:fe96:c83/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: veth3984136: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether ae:35:39:1c:bd:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ac35:39ff:fe1c:bdc1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You are going to have a really hard time debugging this without a pod network. Why don't you have one? Are you using Calico?

Comment: @jaxxstorm, I don't use Calico, it's just a single node setup, for multi-node cluster I use kops

Comment: If this is a single node, and no overlay, then I would expect you can reach the container independent of the k8s setup. I don't know the protocol of anon-svc, but just for testing from the 67.205.156.80 host I would expect `curl -v 172.23.6.158:8125` to at least attempt to connect. Similar with `curl -v 172.17.0.4:8125` (which is what will actually happen, as seen in the iptables-save)

Answer (score 2):

> "targetPort": "agent"

I don't think this is valid style in normal service yaml, could you change it to normal port like 8080 and try again.

Comment: That's not the issue, works fine in other cases. From kubernetes official documentation: _"Perhaps more interesting is that targetPort can be a string, referring to the name of a port in the backend Pods."_

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe share your deployment where the svc is referring to? Make sure your selector in the svc is pointing to the same, in your case name, label.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436841/request-to-localhost-from-pod-via-its-own-service-does-not-work) with the similar problem not specific to a cloud provider. It seems this is a default behavior (can't access own service) when using iptables as a proxy mode.